# Laravel model doesn't refresh its ID after running a seeder

Tags: laravel, eloquent

After running a seeder the model doesn't know that there is already data on the database, so it tries to insert on id 1 even though there is a record already.

Seeder:

```
public function run()
    {
        DB::table('address_type')->insert(array (
            0 =>
            array (
                'id' => '1',
                'name' => 'Residencial',
            ),
            1 =>
            array (
                'id' => '2',
                'name' => 'Comercial',
            ),
        ));
    }
```

Database after seeder:

```
id | name
----------------
1  | Residencial
2  | Comercial
```

But when trying to insert using the controller:

```
"SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "address_type_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists. (SQL: insert into "address_type" ("name", "created_by", "updated_at", "created_at") values (teste, 2, 2020-07-02 16:47:24, 2020-07-02 16:47:24) returning "id")"
```

Code of the controller:

```
$data = $request->all();
$data['created_by'] = Auth::id();
$resultado = $this->repository->create($data);

return response()->json($resultado);
```

Is there any way to sync the model with the database?

Comment: don't set the id in the seeder, its an autoincrement field ... just let it run and sequence itself ... you are probably messing with the sequence when doing it that way

Comment: That did it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the 'id' in the seeder fixed the problem.